# $('.slick').on('swipe') hijack normal swipe/scroll.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari, slick.js

I encounter a problem where if the slide is bigger than the screen, I am unable to slide/swipe down if the slide is bind to a swipe event.

this can only recreated on the ios device, everything works fine with chrome's build-iin emulator, I hadn't had time to test it on others.

anyone have experience on how to fix this?

```js
$('.slides').slick();
$('.slides').on('swipe', function(event, slick, direction) {});
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  padding: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slide" style="background-color: red; height:5000px">
    this is a slide i can slide right but when bind with swipe, I am unable to move down in iso safari this 3000px in height!!!
  </div>
  <div class="slide" style="background-color:yellow; height:3000px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working here.